# unable to mount dongle/modem iball airways 21.0MP-58

Tags: mount

Error mounting /dev/sr1 at /media/arbind/iBall Airway: Command-line `

```
mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sr1" "/media/arbind/iBall Airway"
mount: /dev/sr1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr1 is already mounted or /media/arbind/iBall Airway busy
```

Comment: i am always getting the same problem whenever i plugged in please, help me to get rid of this unmount problem

Answer (score 0):

It's already mounted.`sudo umount "/media/arbind/iBall Airway"` first.

Check the device to see if it has a hardware write-disable switch.

You can see how it is mounted with `mount | grep /dev/sr1`.

If, as you say, it's a "dongle/modem iball airways 21.0MP-58", I wonder why you are trying to mount it as a disk.